# Windows Server 2008 ADS Physical to VM: Strange Date issue

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008, physical-to-virtual

I have recently Converted a physical Active Directory running Server 2008 to VM. (need to move ADS to 2019 Server) and ADS health check reported some issue, which include license activation.

I tied to Activate the windows (existing and also I have a new Key), but windows failed to activate and gives error: 0x80072F8F

Google says that it is a date & time error. I looked closely and system Date time are 100% correct and are synced with 0.pool.ntp.org, 1.pool.ntp.org, 2.pool.ntp.org.

Moreover When opened Chrome, It says your Date is Ahead.
I kept moving in backdate till I found 2017-04-05 (5th April 2017), at this date Chrome stopped complaining that my date is behind, but still gives me SSL error.

I could not find any correlation of 2017-04-05  with anything.
I am not sure what is going on with this VM.

Software are able to pick correct System date, but why the correct date is labeled as future date. and how to activate windows over internet and move ADS to Server 2019

Thank You

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean when you say the current date is labeled as a future date.  What is telling you that?

Comment: Is the the new instance running WinSvr 2008 or 2019?

Comment: @uSlackr when I open google chrome, chrome says, your date is ahead, although the date & time is 100% correct. it is a server 2008 VM that I converted from Physical to VM

Comment: Check your Time**zone** Settings. The same time (e.g. 16:15) ist not the same in Japan and Iceland.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the VM syncing time with the host as well as with NTP.  This is a conflict and likely a race condition if the host server is in the same domain as the guest DC.  Disable the host time sync and let AD do its thing for time.

Comment: I have already disabled the integration services in hyper-V, and AD is managing its time itself, moreover, the host date & time is also perfect.